# How can i write Focus Gained event for Particular column in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my project i have used JTable to billing. In first column i will give some number as input like 1 when i click tab button second column should display name of the product. I wrote it for mouse clicked event. But i dont know how to write it for focus gained. Am using Netbeans IDE.

```
    if(table.getSelectedColumn() == 1)
    {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
        int code = Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        if(code < 1 || code > 48)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Enter Correct Product Code");
            return;
        }
        if(table.getValueAt(row, 0) != null)
        {
            table.setValueAt(tamil.get(code-1), row, 1);
        }
    }
```

This is my code its working fine for mouse clicked. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wrote it for mouse clicked event.

Don't write code for a mouse event. What it the user uses the tab key to move to the next cell?

Instead implement a general solution by overriding the `setValueAt(...)` method of your TableModel.

When you change the value in the first column do your lookup and change the value in the second column. Something like:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
{
    super.setValueAt(value, row, column);

    if (column == 0)
    {
        String name = lookupName(...);
        super.setValueAt(name, row, 1);
    }
}
```